# LXD/LXC containers on NAS via iSCSI. Possible?

Tags: lxc, nas, lxd

Given:
Several hosts with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
NAS with FreeNAS onboard,
They're connected by LAN.

Is it possible to use NAS for storing containers with their filesystem so any host will be able to run any container from pool? Aswell as 'live migration' by stoping the container, storing it's current state on NAS and then starting on another host?

Thanks in advance!